# Panel background not being changed by UI manager

Tags: java, swing

In my program I would like the user to be able to change the colour scheme of the program. I have a method which passes in a colour to set the background of all the panels using UIManager.

```
public void changeColourScheme(Color c) {
        UIManager.put("Panel.background", c);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    }
```

However the issue I'm running into is that it is not changing the colour of the panels. This method is located in the class for the JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply because the `UIDefaults` changes is only effective for the **newly created components**

for your feature to work you have to make the app restart then before starting the gui change the background in the defaults in the `UIManager` , or you will have to do it manually (panel by panel).

if you do it manually recursion will help a lot ,like this

```
private static void loopForPanel(Container c, Color col) {
        synchronized (c.getTreeLock()) {
            for (Component com : c.getComponents()) {
                if (com instanceof JPanel) {
                    com.setBackground(col);
                }
                if (com instanceof Container) {
                    loopForPanel((Container) com,col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then in your `changeColourScheme` method pass the frame it self for the `loopForPanel` method with your desired color.

Answer (score 1):

Copied directly from [Swing API Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component)).

> public static void updateComponentTreeUI(Component c)
>
> A simple minded look and feel change: ask each node in ***the tree***
>   to updateUI() -- that is, to initialize its UI property with the
>   current look and feel.

Notice the emphasize. Your code doesn't work because you are passing `this` as the argument to `updateComponentTreeUI()`. Since you are passing your panel as the argument, only the components inside the panel and the panel itself will get their UI updated. You have to pass the container that holds all other panels in your program, that is your `JFrame`

```
public void changeColourScheme(Color c) {
   UIManager.put("Panel.background", c);
   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame); //instace of your frame
}
```